# ASP.Net Set type from string

Tags: asp.net

This is probably a dumb question, but is it possible to use a type in an expression - kinda like this:

```
Dim X as string = "label"
Dim y as <x>
```

that kind of a thing?

The basic issue is that I have a bunch of strongly typed reports and I want to build a class that can call them... so, I'll know from the db the name of the report, but I'm not sure how to have the class produce the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and why would you want to? Even if VB let you write the second line and compile it, it wouldn't know anything about the type of `y` at *compile time*, so what difference would it be if you just declare it `As Object`, then?

Or do you want to create an *object instance* when name of class at run-time is a string (i.e. `Dim y As Object = New <x>()`)?

Comment: Yeah - I didn't really think so... it's a weird case. I'm using Telerik's reports... so I just need to pass the right report to the report display control. That's all just a matter of sending a report object. Their reports are basically each their own class though - and I wanted to control some permissions for those reports from the db. So, I couldn't think of a way to do it without hard coding the reports into the report class - I guess that's what I'll have to do. It's certainly not the end of the world or anything.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider posting a new question about your _original_ problem, and putting some relevant code for your classes there. It may be something that can be solved with generic classes and interfaces, by the sound of it.